# Object doesn't support this property vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
'Copy and Paste the format of table
        With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
            .Copy
        End With

        Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        cell.Offset(3, 3).Activate

        With wbTarget.Sheets(I).ActiveCell
            .PasteSpecial
        End With
```

On the 3rd paragraph, it gives me the error. I want to paste the contents that I copied into the activecell.

How can I fix this? thanks

Comment: you are using `Activate` between your `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` - which is not needed anyway, it just slows down your code

Comment: replace `wbTarget.Sheets(I).ActiveCell` with `ActiveCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve with your code, I think `ActiveSheet` is also `wbTarget.Sheets(I)` (I hope).

So replace your:

```
Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
cell.Offset(3, 3).Activate

With wbTarget.Sheets(I).ActiveCell
    .PasteSpecial
End With
```

With:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set cell = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    cell.Offset(3, 3).PasteSpecial
End With
```

**Note**: You should stay away from `ActiveSheet` and use the `Worksheets("SheetName")` instead.